# How to scrape Job categories and its sub categories from Upwork website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Friends

I was trying to scrape Category and sub category from following [link](https://www.upwork.com/i/freelancer-categories-all/) using BeautifulSoup in Pyhton.

But I am not able to scrape it gave me blank list all times

I tried following method:

first I tried to scrape only one category from following method but it give e blank output

```
soup.find('h3',{"class":"m-t-40"})
```

I tried to scrape all category but still it give me blank output

```
soup.find_All('h3',{"class":"m-t-40"})
```

Can anyone tell me how to scrape from this link?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.upwork.com/i/freelancer-categories-all/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for section in soup.find_all('section'):
    h3 = section.find('h3', {'class': 'm-t-40'})
    if h3:
        print(h3.text)
        lis = section.find_all('li')
        for li in lis:
            print(li.text.strip())
```

**Output**

```
Web, Mobile & Software Dev

All Web, Mobile & Software Dev
Ecommerce Development

# And many others
```

Comment: Thank you So much @Druta Ruslan. Can you suggest me any good article or link for learn selenium?